# Javascript limit the number of digits displayed

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm struggling to find the right JavaScript code for the following problem.
What I'm trying to do is convert metres in to miles, which I have done successfully, the issue is I only want to show 2 digits, due to lack of display space

example:

if the number is `.0123456789` only want to show the first 2 digits which would be `.12` for this I can use `tofixed`, however if the number is `1.23456789` again only want to show the first 2 digits so I would like it to show as `1.2`

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried google? There's example code of exactly this at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: What if the number is `12345`? You only want to show `12`?

Comment: @user3229756 `Math.round()` doesn't do what he wants.

Comment: if the number is `.01234`, why would `.12` be the correct result? It's missing a `0`.

Comment: Hi I've tried tofixed to 1 decimal place which works ok if the number is above 1.0 and I've also tried toprecision which works fine if the number is below .9

Comment: my mistake .1234 = .12

Comment: as the numbers relate to miles I can't see myself walking more than 9 miles so if I had walked 8.123456 miles show it as 8.1

Comment: its a tough one

Comment: Hi Barmar the reason I need the javascript code is for a Fitbit watch I bought. I've only just started to learn code, can I send you the script I have so far not sure where to add the code you have done

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to a string, then call `substr()` to get the first 3 characters. I also remove a leading `0`, so that `0.12` is printed as `.12` instead of `0.1`.

```js
var nums = [ 1.234, 0.1234, 0.0123 ];
nums.forEach(num => console.log(String(num).replace(/^0/, '').substr(0, 3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok prepare for ugly code: :)

```
var num = 2;
var val = 0.2202323414;
var str = "" + val;
var m = str.match("(0\\.0*?)?([1-9][0-9\.]*)");
var zeros = m[1] === undefined ? - (m[2].indexOf(".") || m[2].length) + 1 :         
m[1].length - 1;
var value = Math.round(val * (Math.pow(10,zeros+num-1))) * Math.pow(10, -zeros + 1 - num);
```

Works for below on and above 1. Negative values not covered.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just started to learn code, where do I insert this, would this go in the app index file or the common utils file. This what I have so far.: const Distance = "distance";
const amountDistance = userActivity.today.adjusted[Distance] * 0.000621371 || 0;
dailydistance.text = (amountDistance.toFixed(1));

Comment: this is just test code to run in your console. but here is a jsbin (which I fixed a bug in also) 
EDIT: https://jsbin.com/torojezuqa/edit?js,console

EDIT: please mark as solution and +1 if it solved your problem.

Comment: Please can you help me with one more problem. I have a button which when pressed changes from battery icon to a  text readout of remaining battery % and when pressed again it reverts back to battery icon, would it be possible when the button is pressed it reverts back to the battery icon automatically after 5 seconds.

Comment: The code I have for the button is: batBtn.onactivate = function(evt) {
  if ( switcher === false) {
    myBat.style.display = "none";
    myBatIcn.style.display = "inline";
    myBatRect.style.display = "inline";
    switcher = true;
  } else {
    myBat.style.display = "inline";
    myBatIcn.style.display = "none";
    myBatRect.style.display = "none";
    switcher = false;
  }

Comment: If you like my answers please mark as solved and upvote with the arrows :)
Here is code in jsbin https://jsbin.com/parowociwu/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

```
let x = 12.345345345;
x = x.toFixed(2);
```